# How to extend clearance's back door to allow for 2FA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clearance

I have an application which uses the Clearance gem for authentication, but also implements 2FA. I want to use the "Backdoor" functionality of Clearance for tests, but am unsure how to do this in conjunction with 2FA.

Is there a way I can "hook into" Clearance's Backdoor functionality and set the required 2FA values whenever it is used to sign in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the source of `Clearance::Backdoor`, if you're trying to set extra values on a user model, this might work:

```
  # config/environments/test.rb
  MyRailsApp::Application.configure do
    # ...
    config.middleware.use Clearance::BackDoor do |username|
      user = User.find_by(username: username) # or however you'd find a user
      # set your extra values
      user.x = 'x'
      user.y = 'y'
      # return the user
      user
    end
  end
```

If you want to mess with the request I don't think you can use `Clearance::Backdoor`, but you could [add another Rack middleware after it](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#adding-a-middleware) using `config.middleware.insert_after(Clearance::Backdoor)` (you would have to write your own middleware).

As an alternative, a lot of tests I've seen just mock the piece of code that checks whether a user is signed in, and make it always return `true` (or whatever indicates success).